# Use Amazon SES and Google GSuite for the same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-admin-sdk, amazon-ses, google-workspace

I have a domain that I manage using Amazon Route 53. It contains TXT/MX records of Amazon Simple Email Service, that I use to process incoming email to a certain email address via AWS Lambda. I also need to register the domain to Google Admin, i.e. GSuite so that I may manage my business emails via Google console. How do I achieve this? I tried setting up Google Admin, entered the MX records of Google Mail, but it resulted in failure of AWS SES services.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It isn't possible to split email for a single domain across multiple services like this.  When a sender on the Internet resolves your domain's mail exchanger (MX), the answer must contain a set of one or more hostnames for systems that will all behave identically for any given recipient email address.¹

The easy solution is to create a subdomain for your SES mail, for example `contact.example.com`, and simply use that domain for your SES messages.

If you really need to have all the addresses have exactly the same domain, set up a subdomain for SES as described above, but then configure GSuite to forward messages for the specific addresses that you want to go to SES, such as `info@example.com`, over to `info@contact.example.com`.

GSuite will then accept messages for those addresses, rewrite the recipient address, and hand them over to SES.

> As a G Suite administrator, you can configure numerous email routing and delivery options to suit your organization. For example, you can route mail to Gmail and an external server. Or, you might need to route incoming mail for non-Gmail users. You can also set up routing policies that vary by organization
>
> https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084

¹*behave identically* from the sender's perspective.  How they may handle the message internally is implementation specific, but for any given email address, all of the listed mail exchangers must accept or reject it, because an authoritative response of "No Such User" from any one of these systems will not trigger the sending system to try any of the others.

Comment: This is a programming question you are replying to? Or is this a thoroughly off topic server configuration question you are replying to which should be closed?

Comment: Touché, @Rob.  I follow many of the AWS tags across all SE sites and don't always notice which site the question was actually posted on.  VTC.

Comment: @Rob Did I post my question at an incorrect forum? Can you recommend me another place to do so. I'm quite new here so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your answer, it is really helpful. The redirecting idea seems to suit my need here. I wasn't sure whether we can send email to subdomains too.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i did as you answered, but SES ask for email to be confirmed how a email can be created for subdomain without using gsuite or some other similar service again ?